# How to make a table responsive without using datatables?

Tags: php, html

How to make a table responsive without using datatables and bootstrap . How to split a table in mobile view ?

Comment: Question is too broad without showing any research attempts or code... Please **visit** the **[help center](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)** and take the tour to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post codes and efforts!

Comment: What's wrong with datatables? or Boostrap?

Comment: if you have large data, you don't need tables. Use Bootstrap grid system

Answer (score 0):

use this format 
**html**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.table-responsive {
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   overflow-x: auto;
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
   -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
}
.table {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: To keep up a high quality of SO please avoid answering off-topic questions